# App can't start after I deleted localization and renamed uibutton

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, localization

I made simple app with 2 languages. When it was done I've decided to delete one language (and did so): I deleted language from project-info-localizations.

After that I've tested app on the device (iPhone) and found that app still has additional (deleted) language. Then I've deleted the app from the iPhone and run project again - it had no sense to my changes. I don't understand the reason... However, later I've found mistake (grammar) in the name of the button and renamed it. That action completely killed my app - it can't be run on the iPhone from that very moment.

> Error is: 2013-01-25 11:46:34.087 timeLimiter[13649:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key startAlerButton.'

It mentions "startAlerButton" which was renamed (I've checked all relations in .h, .m, storyboad).

Answer (score 1):

Please check if there is still some connection to outlet startAlerButton in the xib files.

Comment: From my experience, the problem with this kind of crash is always forgotten link in .xib to non existing property in controller, are you  sure that there is outlet startAlerTButton and in xib you are linking startAlerButton? I know that you checked, but am kinda sure that this is the problem.

Comment: Applicaion runs on the iPhone simulator (no errors occur) but not on the device. If the problem is in xib (btw I don't use/see one 'cause Xcode 4.5.2 uses .storyboards) app would't run on the simulator I think.

Comment: It looks like some kind of iPhone cache.

Comment: I found the source of the problem - it was in the AppDelegate.h It contained the declaration one of my methods that used "startAlerButton" IBOutlet. I've deleted mentioned declaration and my application started on the iPhone! @Ivan, thank you anyway)